# Insert filename during bulk load in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
DECLARE @SQL_BULK VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL_BULK = 'BULK INSERT [dbo].[Table]
                 FROM ''' + @BatchFileName + '''
                 WITH
                 (
                     FIRSTROW = 2,
                     FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'',
                     ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a'' 
                 )'

EXEC (@SQL_BULK)
```

I have this code to do a bulk load. Works fine, but I would like to have the `@BatchFileName` also in there as a column (each row contains the same value).

Is this possible during the bulk load? Or how can I add it later on in a separate function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

i use this script to iterate and bulkinsert files in directory:

```
create table #x (name varchar(200))
DECLARE @query varchar (1000),@conta int ,@query2 varchar (1000),@NOME varchar(50)
set @conta=1
set @query ='master.dbo.xp_cmdshell "dir '+'C:\directoryname'+'*.csv' +' /b"'
insert #x exec (@query)
delete from #x where name is NULL
select identity(int,1,1) as ID, name into #y from #x  
drop table #x
WHILE @conta<221 --number of files

BEGIN
SELECT @NOME=name FROM #y WHERE ID=@conta
set @Query2 ='BULK INSERT [dbo].[tablename] FROM '+ '''C:\directoryname'+@NOME+'''
    WITH (
FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a'')' 
SELECT @query2
exec (@Query2)

set @conta=@conta+1

END
drop table #y
```